# Making finite groups out of neat collections of functions.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, function-and-relation-composition

This is a piece of folklore I found on the Internet:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
    \varepsilon = x     & f = 1 - x           \\
    g = \frac{1}{x}     & h = \frac{1}{1 - x} \\
    m = \frac{x - 1}{x} & n = \frac{x}{x - 1}
\end{array}
$$

There are 6 functions, and it is claimed that they form the dihedral group $D_3$ under
composition. I computed some part of the corresponding *(hypothetical yet)* Cayley table, and it
does look like a group. However, the derivations, trivial as they may be, take a lot of paper and
attention to actually perform, and a slight mistake will lead one to believe that this is not a
group. What kind of tricks can I use to find out if this is a group, short of carefully computing
the whole table?

1. It appears that all the functions here are distinct, but technically I should provide for every
   pair of functions a value that differentiates them. For example, $\varepsilon(2) = 2, h(2) = -1$,
   and so on.  This is really so boring. As a shortcut, I may compare limits and observe:

   $$
   \begin{array}{ll}
       \varepsilon \to +\infty & f \to -\infty \\
       g \to 0^+               & h \to 0^-     \\
       m \to 1^-               & n \to 1^+
       \end{array}
   $$

   So far so good.
2. $\varepsilon$ is the identity.
3. $g$ is the multiplicative inverse, so in the group $\langle\mathbb{R}, \times\rangle$ $g \circ g$
   would be $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$, so $g \circ g$ = $\varepsilon$ and we have our first subgroup $Z_2$.

This is about as far as I could get, until I decided to explore the compositional structure of the
given functions. Turns out that I can express them all in terms of these trivial functions:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\alpha & = & x + 1       \\
\beta  & = & -x          \\
\gamma & = & \frac{1}{x}
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
                      & f = \alpha\beta                  \\
g = \gamma            & h = \gamma\alpha\beta            \\
m = \alpha\beta\gamma & n = \alpha\beta\gamma\alpha\beta
\end{array}
$$

Only a handful of simple theorems are enough to infer the whole Cayley table, giving a witness to
group structure:

$$ \beta\beta = \gamma\gamma = \varepsilon \tag{involution} $$
$$ \beta\alpha\beta = \alpha^- \tag{inverse} $$

It took only a page to get there. *(Identity omitted for clarity.)*

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
  & f & g & h & m & n \\
\hline         
f &   & m & n & g & h \\
g & h &   & f & n & m \\
h & g & n & m &   & f \\
m & n & f &   & h & g \\
n & m & h & g & f &   \\
\end{array}
$$

I wonder though if there is a yet simpler way. The given functions are so neat, they are obviously
specially prepared. But I am not seeing how. For example, would it be difficult to offer a
collection of 8 functions that form the group $D_4$ of the symmetries of the square under
composition? Is there some generality I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

To any nonzero point $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can associate a (possibly infinite) slope $s = \frac{y}{x}$. Suppose that under a linear transformation $T$, the point $(x, y)$ is sent to the new point $(ax + by, cx + dy)$. Then the slope of this new point is equal to 
$$\frac{cx + dy}{ax + by} = \frac{ds + c}{bs + a},$$
so we see that linear transformations on $\mathbb{R}^2$ induce so-called "fractional linear transformations" on the slopes of points. The map $\varphi$ taking a linear transformation to its induced fractional linear transformation is a group homomorphism from the group of invertible linear transformations on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (aka GL$_2(\mathbb{R})$) to the group of invertible fractional linear transformations (for both groups the group multiplication is composition). You can straightforwardly compute that the kernel of $\varphi$ is the group of dilations of the plane, so if $G$ is a subgroup of GL$_2(\mathbb{R})$ that doesn't contain any dilations, then $\varphi(G)$ is a collection of fractional linear transformations that is isomorphic to $G$.

For your particular collection of fractional linear transformations, consider the three points $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1,0)$ in the plane. You can compute that the subgroup $G$ of GL$_2(\mathbb{R})$ that stabilizes these points is isomorphic to $D_3$, that $G$ doesn't contain any dilations, and that $\varphi(G)$ is exactly the collection of fractional linear transformations that your post is about. To construct $D_n$ for any odd $n$ out of fractional linear transformations, you can instead start with the stabilizer in GL$_2(\mathbb{R})$ of the vertices of a regular $n$-gon, and apply the same procedure. This won't work to construct $D_n$ for even $n$, since one of the symmetries of an even $n$-gon is 180-degree rotation, which is the same thing as a dilation by a factor of -1. Perhaps there's a more clever geometric construction that one can do.

Comment: Awesome answer! For the future reader: this group is called $\mathrm{PGL}_1(\mathbb{R})$ [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation).